# AWS Cloudwatch log query times out in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm trying to query a log group using a lambda with javascript sdk v3:

```
export const realTimeQueryString = (route_key: string, account: string) => `fields @timestamp, @message | 
    filter route_key = "ANY /${route_key}/{proxy+}" and user != "-"  and account = "${account}" | 
    stats count(*) by account, user, path`;

export const getFirstDayOfMonthTimestamp = (): number => {
  const date = new Date();
  const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
  return Math.floor(firstDayOfMonth.getTime() / 1000);
};


const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export const startQuery = async (queryString: string) => {
  logger.info(`query initiated for ${queryString}`);
  const params: StartQueryCommandInput = {
    logGroupName: 'api_gw_v2',
    queryString: queryString,
    startTime: getFirstDayOfMonthTimestamp(),
    endTime: Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
    limit: 10000,
  };
  logger.info(`init query: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
  const command = new StartQueryCommand(params);
  const response = await client.send(command);
  return response.queryId;
}


export const stopQuery = async (queryId: string) => {
  logger.info(`stopping query: ${JSON.stringify(queryId)}`);
  const command = new StopQueryCommand({ queryId: queryId });
  await client.send(command);
}

export const getQueryResults = async (queryId: string) => {
  logger.info(`Processing results for query: ${queryId}`);
  const command = new GetQueryResultsCommand({ queryId: queryId });
  const result = await client.send(command);
  
  while (result['status'] === 'Running') {
    logger.info(`current result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    logger.info(`waiting for query results to complete...`);
    await sleep(5000);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This code is called in the handler function like this:

```
const apiQueryId = await startQuery(realTimeQueryString('api',  event["account"]));
const apiQueryResults = await getQueryResults(apiQueryId);
```

From the log-group of this function I get the following:

Query with params(logging in startQuery function):

```
{
    "logGroupName": "*****",
    "queryString": "fields @timestamp, @message | \n    filter route_key = \"ANY /mgt/{proxy+}\" and user != \"-\"  and account = \"SmartLaw\" | \n    stats count(*) by account, user, path",
    "startTime": 1690848000,
    "endTime": 1691741668,
    "limit": 10000
}
```

Checking the current results of the query I get this(getQueryResults function):

```
{
    "$metadata": {
        "httpStatusCode": 200,
        "requestId": "******",
        "attempts": 1,
        "totalRetryDelay": 0
    },
    "results": [],
    "statistics": {
        "bytesScanned": 0,
        "recordsMatched": 0,
        "recordsScanned": 0
    },
    "status": "Running"
}
```

I guess it's fair to assume that the query is valid based on statusCode, status, etc. I can also view the history in Logs Insights and run them from there.

I've currently set the timeout of the lambda to 5 minutes, and when testing it from the console the task times out after 5 minutes.

The log is the same for every iteration of the while loop, no results and statistics. [StopQueryCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/cloudwatch-logs/command/StopQueryCommand/) has also been attempted, but this gives the same results and I'm not sure how to determine when to stop the query.

Comment: Have you run the query outside of the lambda and checked how long it actually takes to complete?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, testing the query on the last 4 weeks takes:
44,708 records (24.2 MB) scanned in 7.2s @ 6,207 records/s (3.4 MB/s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getQueryResults` only retrieves the results once and then reuses the old `result` over and over again. The

```
const command = new GetQueryResultsCommand({ queryId: queryId });
const result = await client.send(command);
```

parts needs to be *inside* the `while` loop.